# An open and connected subset $U\subseteq \mathbb C$ is still connected if you remove a curve that lies entirely in $U$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb C$ be open and connected. If $f\colon [0,1]\to U$ is continuous with $f(0)\neq f(1)$ and $f(s)\neq f(t)$ for $s\neq t$, then $U\setminus f([0,1])$ is connected.

This seems to be "obviously true", so I'm looking for a proof. What I have so far:

As $U$ is open, it is path-connected. I want to show, that $V:=U\setminus f([0,1])$ is path-connected as well. Let $a,b\in U$, then we have $\varphi\colon[0,1]\to U$ continuous with $\varphi(0)=a$ and $\varphi(1)=b$. If $\varphi([0,1])\subset V$ we're done. Now assume that $\varphi([0,1])\notin V$.

For sufficient small $\varepsilon>0$ we have $0=t_0<\dots <t_n=1$ with $$f([t_{j-1},t_j])\in K_{\varepsilon}(f(t_j)\subset U,~j=1,\dots n$$ where $K_{\varepsilon}(f(t_j))$ denotes the open disk with radius $\varepsilon$ and origin $f(t_j)$.

I want to cover the curve $f$ with small, overlapping circles, so when $\varphi$ gets near $f$, it first has to cross over $\partial K_{\varepsilon}(f(t_i))$ and I can use the $\partial K_{\varepsilon}(f(t_i))$ to get "around $f$".

[image]

I have proven, that such circles as above exist, but do they always overlap?

Edit: for my application it is enough to further assume that $f$ is differentiable. This might help/I might have an idea that I'll think through.

Comment: I think (just intuitively) that these epsilons, they won't all be the same. You may need to vary them based on some local properties of the curve.

Comment: @peter.petrov, I have proof that they are. ;)

Edit: not the same for every curve of course, but for a fixed curve I find such epsilon as described.

Comment: OK, sorry ;) was just thinking out loud.

Comment: No need to be sorry, every input is appreciated. :)

Comment: This is the "Jordan arc theorem", and if you search that term on math.stackexchange and on mathoverflow you'll find closely related questions. However, most of those questions prove something stronger and/or use big cannons. So I still think the best proof---meaning simplest, using the least technology---is in Munkres topology book (theorem 13.3 in the old version of his book). Nonetheless, the proof in Munkres is not as straightforward as what you are suggesting, in particular it uses a special version of the Van Kampen theorem.

Comment: Yes, you said it's not a closed curve. You need to think about the case where the curve is closed anyway; if you think you've converted the above into an actual proof a good check is whether the same proof would work for a closed curve, in which case the proof is wrong. In particular, when you use those circles to get around $f$ there has to be some point in the argument that uses the fact that $f$ is not closed.

Comment: @LeeMosher thank you for the name of the theorem and literature, I'll look if I can get the book by Munkres.

My own attempt seems to be so simple and obvious, but I just can't put it all together. I think I'll give it a few more tries during the next days, though. Thank you very much, all of you. :)

Comment: Re : Overlapping discs: If $D$ is an open disc of your collection and $f(x)\in D$ let $x^-=\inf \{t\leq x :f([t,x])\subset D\}$ and $x^+=\sup \{t\geq x: f([x,t])\subset D.$  If $D$ does not cover the whole curve $f([0,1])$ then $f(x^-)\in \bar D$  \ $D$  or $f(x^+)\in \bar D$ \ $D$ .... If  $f(x^-)\in \bar D$ \ $D$ then $f(x^-)$ belongs to an open disc $ E $ of your collection with  $E\cap D \ne \phi.$

Comment: closely related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209076/showing-that-arcs-do-not-separate-the-plane-mathbbr2